# What parameters to put in keypair instance in boto python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, key-pair

I'm trying to create a keyPair instance and this is what I have. What would I put in the parameters of the create_key_pair function? I thought it would be the key, but it is giving me an error that says I am unauthorized to perform this action. Any help would be appreciated!

```
#establish connection to the region
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1', aws_access_key_id= aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret_access_key )


#create the key pair
response = conn.create_key_pair(aws_secret_access_key, False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the following permission to create an EC2 Key Pair:

```
ec2:DescribeKeyPairs (to select a key pair)
ec2:CreateKeyPair (to create a key pair)
```

Example to create a key pair (boto3):

```
    import boto3
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1', aws_access_key_id='<access_key>',
aws_secret_access_key='<secret_key>')
    key = ec2.create_key_pair(KeyName='MY_KEY_PAIR_NAME')
    print(key)
```

OR (boto):

```
    import boto.ec2
    conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1',
                                      aws_access_key_id='<access_key>',
                                      aws_secret_access_key='<secret_key>')
    key = ec2.create_key_pair('MY_KEY_PAIR_NAME')
    print key
```

Comment: is the MY_KEY_PAIR_NAME an arbitrary name we give to it?

Comment: Yes, replace with the name for your key pair name. This is the name displayed in the EC2 console.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not working. I am getting the following error:                                   boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>UnauthorizedOperation</Code><Message>You are not authorized to perform this operation.</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>72a49944-48dc-4707-9b4d-5b12b767a1cd</RequestID></Response>

Comment: This means that the credentials that you supplied are either wrong (typo) or do not have permission to create a key pair. Where did your access key come from? What policy is attached to the user that created the access key? You will find these details in the Amazon IAM console. Update your question with these details. Note: do not include your access key in your question. Suggestion, go to the IAM console and create a new set of keys and try those. Make sure that the user's policy grants EC2 permissions.

Comment: Yes! Regenerating the keys worked! Thank you for your help.